# Microsoft Teams Chat History clear after 1 day

Tags: microsoft-teams

We enabled Teams retention policy but it is not allowing us to set it to 1 day. Is there any script which we can run on local user machines to clear chat history after 24hrs.

When try to make change policy online, it gives error that you can apply retention policy for less than 30 days.

There is no error message but it is not working

Comment: Can you please describe exactly how you set the policy?

Comment: In Office 365 Security and Compliance/data governance/retention/ create policy and  assigned it to users.

Comment: _"When try to make change policy online, it gives error that you can apply retention policy for less than 30 days."_ Do you mean "cannot apply"?

Comment: It applies but we are looking for any workaround to make it for 1 day. 30 days is violation of our legal policy.